# SALABIM how to minimize memory requirements

Tags: python, memory, simulation, simpy

I am using the [Salabim package](https://www.salabim.org/) in python to simulate some queueing theory. Salabim [(documentation)](https://www.salabim.org/manual/) is based on [SimPy](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but with many extensions and additional features.
Most of my problems are solved in a few minutes with minimal memory requirements.

However, I want to extend the model and noted that the simulation captures about 32GB after 1 hour of simulation of a simple M/M/1 queueing problem. I expect this is due to some internal monitors capturing statistical data. I have tried to deactivate most of them but till now without success.

> **- What statement am I missing?**
> **- What can I change to minimize memory requirements?**

*Please note that I switch of monitoring for each class with the following code*:

```
    def setup(self):
        self.mode.monitor(False)
        self.status.monitor(False) # added 17 nov, salabim team tip
```

## Code

```
# passivate/activate method
# https://www.salabim.org/manual/Modelling.html#a-bank-example

import salabim as sim


class CarGenerator(sim.Component):
    def setup(self):
        self.mode.monitor(False)
        self.status.monitor(False) # added 17 nov, salabim team tip

    def process(self):
        while True:
            Car()
            self.hold(iat_distr.sample())


class Car(sim.Component):
    def setup(self):
        self.mode.monitor(False)
        self.status.monitor(False) # added 17 nov, salabim team tip

    def process(self):
        self.enter(waitingline)
        for ChargingStation in ChargingStations:
            if ChargingStation.ispassive():
                ChargingStation.activate()
                break  # activate at most one charging station
        self.passivate()


class ChargingStation(sim.Component):
    def setup(self):
        self.mode.monitor(False)
        self.status.monitor(False)  # added 17 nov, salabim team tip

    def process(self):
        while True:
            while len(waitingline) == 0:
                self.passivate()
            self.car = waitingline.pop()
            self.hold(srv_distr.sample())
            self.car.activate()


N_STATION = 1
iat_distr = sim.Exponential(60 / 40)
srv_distr = sim.Exponential(60 / 50)

# https://www.salabim.org/manual/Reference.html#environment
app = sim.App(
    trace=False,  # defines whether to trace or not
    random_seed="*",  # if “*”, a purely random value (based on the current time)
    time_unit="minutes",  # defines the time unit used in the simulation
    name="Charging Station",  # name of the simulation
    do_reset=True,  # defines whether to reset the simulation when the run method is called
    yieldless=True,  # defines whether the simulation is yieldless or not
)

# Instantiate and activate the client generator
CarGenerator(name="Electric Cars Generator")

# Create Queue and set monitor to stats_only
waitingline = sim.Queue(name="Waiting Cars", monitor=False)
waitingline.length_of_stay.monitor(value=True)
waitingline.length_of_stay.reset_monitors(stats_only=True)

# Instantiate the servers, list comprehension but only 1 server
ChargingStations = [ChargingStation() for _ in range(N_STATION)]

# Execute Simulation
app.run(till=sim.inf)

# Print statistics
waitingline.length_of_stay.print_statistics()
```

## Environment

I am running `'CPython'` with `python version 3.9.18` and `SALABIM version 23.3.11.1` on Ubuntu 22.04 on a Windows Subsystem for Linux (but same happens on a pure Ubuntu 22.04 system)

WSL version: 1.2.5.0
Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
WSLg version: 1.0.51
MSRDC version: 1.2.3770
Direct3D version: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.19045.3693

## Packages

The following ENV.yml file can be used to recreate the conda environment or check package versions.

```
name: mem_salabim
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - nodefaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge
  - _openmp_mutex=4.5=2_gnu
  - anyio=4.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - argon2-cffi=23.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - argon2-cffi-bindings=21.2.0=py39hd1e30aa_4
  - arrow=1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - asttokens=2.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - async-lru=2.0.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - attrs=23.1.0=pyh71513ae_1
  - babel=2.13.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - backports=1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_3
  - backports.functools_lru_cache=1.6.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - beautifulsoup4=4.12.2=pyha770c72_0
  - bleach=6.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - brotli-python=1.1.0=py39h3d6467e_1
  - bzip2=1.0.8=hd590300_5
  - ca-certificates=2023.7.22=hbcca054_0
  - cached-property=1.5.2=hd8ed1ab_1
  - cached_property=1.5.2=pyha770c72_1
  - certifi=2023.7.22=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - cffi=1.16.0=py39h7a31438_0
  - charset-normalizer=3.3.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - comm=0.1.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - debugpy=1.8.0=py39h3d6467e_1
  - decorator=5.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - defusedxml=0.7.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - entrypoints=0.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - exceptiongroup=1.1.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - executing=2.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - fqdn=1.5.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - greenlet=3.0.1=py39h3d6467e_0
  - idna=3.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - importlib-metadata=6.8.0=pyha770c72_0
  - importlib_metadata=6.8.0=hd8ed1ab_0
  - importlib_resources=6.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - ipykernel=6.26.0=pyhf8b6a83_0
  - ipython=8.17.2=pyh41d4057_0
  - isoduration=20.11.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jedi=0.19.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jinja2=3.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - json5=0.9.14=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jsonpointer=2.4=py39hf3d152e_3
  - jsonschema=4.19.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jsonschema-specifications=2023.7.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jsonschema-with-format-nongpl=4.19.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter-lsp=2.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_client=8.6.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_core=5.5.0=py39hf3d152e_0
  - jupyter_events=0.9.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_server=2.10.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_server_terminals=0.4.4=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - jupyterlab=4.0.8=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyterlab_pygments=0.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyterlab_server=2.25.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.40=h41732ed_0
  - libffi=3.4.2=h7f98852_5
  - libgcc-ng=13.2.0=h807b86a_3
  - libgomp=13.2.0=h807b86a_3
  - libnsl=2.0.1=hd590300_0
  - libsodium=1.0.18=h36c2ea0_1
  - libsqlite=3.44.0=h2797004_0
  - libstdcxx-ng=13.2.0=h7e041cc_3
  - libuuid=2.38.1=h0b41bf4_0
  - libzlib=1.2.13=hd590300_5
  - markupsafe=2.1.3=py39hd1e30aa_1
  - matplotlib-inline=0.1.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - mistune=3.0.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbclient=0.8.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbconvert-core=7.11.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbformat=5.9.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - ncurses=6.4=h59595ed_2
  - nest-asyncio=1.5.8=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - notebook=7.0.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - notebook-shim=0.2.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - openssl=3.1.4=hd590300_0
  - overrides=7.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - packaging=23.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pandocfilters=1.5.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - parso=0.8.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pexpect=4.8.0=pyh1a96a4e_2
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=py_1003
  - pip=23.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pkgutil-resolve-name=1.3.10=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - platformdirs=4.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - prometheus_client=0.18.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.41=pyha770c72_0
  - prompt_toolkit=3.0.41=hd8ed1ab_0
  - psutil=5.9.5=py39hd1e30aa_1
  - ptyprocess=0.7.0=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - pure_eval=0.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pygments=2.16.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=pyha2e5f31_6
  - python=3.9.18=h0755675_0_cpython
  - python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-fastjsonschema=2.18.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-json-logger=2.0.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python_abi=3.9=4_cp39
  - pytz=2023.3.post1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyyaml=6.0.1=py39hd1e30aa_1
  - pyzmq=25.1.1=py39h8c080ef_2
  - readline=8.2=h8228510_1
  - referencing=0.30.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - requests=2.31.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - rfc3339-validator=0.1.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - rfc3986-validator=0.1.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - rpds-py=0.12.0=py39h9fdd4d6_0
  - send2trash=1.8.2=pyh41d4057_0
  - setuptools=68.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyh6c4a22f_0
  - sniffio=1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - soupsieve=2.5=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - stack_data=0.6.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - terminado=0.18.0=pyh0d859eb_0
  - tinycss2=1.2.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tk=8.6.13=noxft_h4845f30_101
  - tomli=2.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tornado=6.3.3=py39hd1e30aa_1
  - traitlets=5.13.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - types-python-dateutil=2.8.19.14=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - typing-extensions=4.8.0=hd8ed1ab_0
  - typing_extensions=4.8.0=pyha770c72_0
  - typing_utils=0.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tzdata=2023c=h71feb2d_0
  - uri-template=1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - urllib3=2.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - wcwidth=0.2.10=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - webcolors=1.13=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - webencodings=0.5.1=pyhd8ed1ab_2
  - websocket-client=1.6.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - wheel=0.41.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - xz=5.2.6=h166bdaf_0
  - yaml=0.2.5=h7f98852_2
  - zeromq=4.3.5=h59595ed_0
  - zipp=3.17.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pip:
      - salabim==23.3.11.1
prefix: /home/floris/miniforge3/envs/jads_salabim
```

Comment: I see that you created `setup` methods that execute `self.mode.monitor(False)`, but I don't see these methods called.  Do you call those methods somewhere?  If not, what is their purpose?

Comment: Did you mean for the `setup` methods to actually be `__init__` methods?

Comment: salabim automatically call the setup method on creation. A kind of __init__ method for dummies.

Comment: I added ```self.status.monitor(False)``` for each class based on a tip from Salabim.org. It reduces memory consumption but not all. After running simulation for a few hours all my 32 GB is consumed again, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried calling `sys.getsizeof` on the names in your scope to see if you can find the memory hog?

Comment: Hi joe, thanks for the suggestion. didn't do that yet, will try. 
Just posted the solution offered by Ruud van der Ham the core Salabim developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On 28 November 2023 a new version (23.3.12) of Salabim package has been released which solves this issue and doesn't need the patch anymore as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Dear Salabim Magicians,

The core developer of Salabim has suggested a patch which indeed solved the problem completely. I have tested the solution by running this very simple toy example with the patch applied (see below) for over 10 hours simulating 400 Million cars being charged.

> **Memory consumption didn't increase at all!!!**

[image: 10 hours of simulation]
[image: memory still stable]

**Solution**

elegant and simple with huge impact

Instead of

```
Car()
```

use

```
Car(name="Car")
```

Comment: That's strange. Did the developer explain why that stops the memory leak? Sounds like a bug in the source code.

Comment: Hi Joe, this is the reply:

the -arguably- memory leak, made me reconsider the way names are serialized. And implemented a new way to do that, which might affect the sequence_number of components, queues, monitors, etc. But I doubt whether this is a major problem in existing models.
The upcoming version will incorporate this new way. Stay tuned.

btw could you indicate wheter the answer is useful so others will also find it before the patch?